# Python 3 - How to do something while the timer counts down

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, countdown

So my problem is about countdown timers. I'm a beginner and I'm trying to get to do something while a timer is ticking down.

Here is the countdown timer (I won't lie, I copied the template from StackOverflow):

```
while t:
    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
    timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
    print(timeformat)
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1
```

And this is what I want to do while it's counting down:

```
hit = 0
miss = 0    

while StartTimer(setTime):
    bucha = input()

    if bucha == 'a':
        print('Hit!')
        hit += 1

    elif bucha == 's':
        print('Miss!')
        miss += 1
```

The second while loop isn't important now, it's the first that bothers me. While the timer is counting down, I can't do anything because of `time.sleep(1)`. There has to be a solution, but I can't seem to find it. I'd be grateful if someone solved this or pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: `time.sleep` blocks anything else from happening. If you want to do things "in parallel", look into threading/multiprocessing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `gevent` to get non-blocking `sleep`.

Comment: Do also note (as per the warning in the docs) that `time.sleep` and friends are not perfectly reliable timers. YMMV on how long it actually sleeps.